# PendingIntent with the same ID

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Is it possible to create two PendingIntents with the same ID ( let's say 889) and the same intent (but different bundle) and then when I cancel PendingIntent with ID 889 will it cancel it both ?

Comment: Why create 2 pendingIntents with same ID?

Comment: I wanna create repeating alarms. Repeating alarm for monday and tuesday. And I want that to be one alarm. And to be possible to cancel it at once

Comment: Let the alarm on monday be called first, and then schedule the alarm for tuesday after dismissing it.

Comment: I need alarm to repeat every monday and every tuesday or some other combination like alarm workout (mon, wed, fri), alarm job (mon, tue, wed, th, fri) ...

Comment: You can manually set this repetition. There is no need of simultaneous scheduling of 4 different alarms for 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cant do that.
The System uses the ID to identify the Intents. So if you get a result you never know which of your Intents being processed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different IDs if you want to set a  repeating alarm for 2 different days. Because if you'll use the same id for each then the notification you set the latest will override the previous one and hence you'll have lose one notification.